# How should i fix npm run deps/dev not working after removing package.json

Tags: node.js, macos, npm

i removed ~/package.json and now i tried to install this [SwitchyOmega](https://github.com/FelisCatus/SwitchyOmega).
the first steps works fine

```
# Install node and npm first (make sure npm --version > 2.0), then:

sudo npm install -g grunt-cli bower
```

but the next step

```
# In the project folder:
cd omega-build
npm run deps # This runs npm install in every module.
npm run dev # This runs npm link to aid local development.
```

give me this error

```
npm ERR! path /Users/Rahimi/package.json
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/Rahimi/package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/Rahimi/.npm/_logs/2017-09-17T04_55_31_851Z-debug.log
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The script commands you are trying to run are present in `package.json` as shown below.

```
    "scripts": {
       "deps": "npm install && (cd ../omega-pac && npm install) && (cd ../omega-target && npm install) && (cd ../omega-web && npm install && bower install) && (cd ../omega-target-chromium-extension/ && npm install)",
       "dev": "(cd ../omega-pac && npm run dev) && (cd ../omega-target && npm run dev) && (cd ../omega-web && npm run dev) && (cd ../omega-target-chromium-extension/ && npm run dev)"
    }
```

If you remove `package.json` you won't be able to run these commands. you need `package.json` to install packages through script command.

To do this without `package.json` you have to navigate to each folder mentioned in the command `deps` and run `npm install` to install pacakges. run `dev`  command by navigating to mentioned folders in the main `dev` command. which is quite a lot of work, It is better to keep `pacakge.json` and use the script command.

Comment: how can i reinstall my package.json ?

Comment: you can visit the link you mentioned in the [question](https://github.com/FelisCatus/SwitchyOmega/blob/master/omega-build/package.json). inside the `omega-build` folder you'll get `package.json` file. put it in your local repository. That will work for you